# How to manage Laravel file cache for multi tenant using same codebase

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-cache

Laravel:5.6
Php:7.1

I am having multiple tenants(platforms) application with the single codebase and using the file cache. I need to handle the cache removal for specific platform.

I tried to set the cache config storage path on runtime to set the different cache paths with respect to the platforms. But it got the default settings from config/cache.php once I try to put the cache using the following method

```
Cache::store('file')->put($key, $data, CACHE_MINUTES);
```

Comment: I'd change the keys to be something tenant specific. So for example add a prefix to the cache keys which is unique per tennant.

Comment: @Tuim thanks for your response, but I think so the prefix only works using APC or Memcached. However, I am using the file based cache.

Comment: `$key = $tennant->id.'-'.$key` Something like this would work I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

How do you set cache config? Is it like

```
config(['cache.stores.file.path'=>$tenantPath]);
Cache::store('file')->put($key, $data, CACHE_MINUTES);
```